# Best approach to load a PartialView depending on a drop down (MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Let me explain what is the scenario. In the following image, I've got a dropdown and a div box, the dropdown always have two options, when this is changed should have to load a PartialView in the div box.

And when the page loads the first time, should show the first option of the dropdown.

[image]

Now I'm gonna show you my code.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Monitor(short id, string viewBy = "class")
    {
        var model = db.Assignments.Find(id);

        List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>()
        {
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "Class", Value = "class" },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "TEKS", Value = "teks" }
        };

        MonitorViewModel vm = new MonitorViewModel
        {
            AssignmentId = model.AssignmentId,
            AssignmentName = model.Name,
            ViewBy = list,
            SelectedView = viewBy
        };

        return View(vm);
    }

    public ActionResult MonitorContentView(short assignmentId, string viewBy)
    {
        if (viewBy.Equals("class"))
            return MonitorByClass(assignmentId);
        else
            return MonitorByTEKS(assignmentId);
    }

    public ActionResult MonitorByClass(short assignmentId) { ... }
    public ActionResult MonitorByTEKS(short assignmentId) { ... }
```

My razor view

```
@model Contoso.MvcApplication.ViewModels.Stats.MonitorViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Monitor";
}

<hgroup>
    <h2>Monitor</h2>
    <h3>@Model.AssignmentName</h3>
</hgroup>

<div>
    <span>View by: </span>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.SelectedView, Model.ViewBy, new { id = "monitorViewByDropDown" })
</div>

@using (Html.BeginForm(new { id = "monitorForm" })) {
<div id="monitor-content-view">
    @Html.Action("MonitorByClass", new { assignmentId = @Model.AssignmentId })
</div>
}
```

So, when user change the drop down value, should have to get the partial view through AJAX (I still have not implemented) calling `MonitorContentView` passing the value in it.

Which I'm doing is a good implementation? Or is there another better approach?
I want to know if the way about loading the partial view is fine.

Comment: You can use trigger the loading on the change event using jQuery. Here's an example. [Dynamically load partial views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313444/dynamically-load-partial-views/11321563#11321563)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a complex view in `monitor-content-view`, that is returned by either the `MonitorByClass` or `MonitorByTEKS` then it's best that you return a `ViewResult`. If each view, that represents the two methods mentioned, is not that complex then it's better to return a json result and populate your view on the client side. This is even better if the two views share common fields where some fields are hidden/shown based on which method was called.

Comment: In fact, each view has its own view model. So I guess these does not share the same properties